# How can I inflate my child fragments into activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, pagerslidingtabstrip

I want to implement SlidingTabs with view pager. I followed the steps specified [in this link](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html). There is only one difference in my situation. I am using fragment instead of activity. So in this situation I want to inflate child fragments when user press the tabs.

Here how I tried to do this :

```
//I am using navigation drawer in my activity and when user press one item it create a fragment which I want to show many child fragments using tabs
@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {

    switch (position){
        case 3 :
            mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            mFragment = new MainFragment().newInstance(mHelpLiveo.get(position).getName());

            if (mFragment != null){
                mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, mFragment).commit();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

my onCreateView function in my MainFragment.java :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_tabs, container, false);

    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.

    //EDİT 3 :
    adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(this.getChildFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.private_public_pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_grey_900);
        }
    });

    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    return rootView;
}
```

in my ViewPagerAdapter class :

```
//This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    if(position == 0) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
    {
        Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
        return tab1;
    }
    else             // As we are having 2 tabs if the position is now 0 it must be 1 so we are returning second tab
    {
        Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
        return tab2;
    }

}
```

anything else is same with [the link I provided above](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html).

Edit 1 :

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.melomg.example.ui.MainFragment">

<com.melomg.example.ui.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="@color/myColor"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/private_public_pager"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

in mainfragment.xml file only SlidingTabLayout appears I am not able to see Vİew Pager.

Edit 2 :

some screens to explain my application.

[image: my main activity with navigation drawer. when user press one item my main fragment is created]
my main activity with navigation drawer. when user press one item my main fragment is created

[image]
my main fragment to show tabs. but view pager can not be seen.

Comment: instead of getFragmentManager() use getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: I was using this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() in my main fragment. how can I call getChildFragmentManager ?

Comment: adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(this.getChildFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs); I did like this. But still I am not able to see my tab fragments.

Comment: Use `TabLayout` with `ViewPager`, it'll help you to improve flow of projects. Even you can use multiple nested Fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mainfragment.xml layout, the LinearLayout orientation is set to horizontal, so the items are on the same line horizontally. The SlidingTabLayout's width is match_parent so the ViewPager is squished to it's right with width 0. Simply change the orientation to 'vertical'

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.melomg.example.ui.MainFragment">

...

</LinearLayout>
```